# Is it possible to include socketmodule.h in Python C extensions?

Tags: python-c-extension, python-extensions

I'd like to invoke  PySocketModule_ImportModuleAndAPI function defined in socketmodule.h in my Python C-extension.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  There's even some documentation in the [socketmodule.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/socketmodule.h) as to how to do it:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by:

1. Adding the Modules\ directory (from your Python source) to the C/C++ Additional Include Directories.
2. #include "socketmodule.h"

Don't know if this is the best solution, but it worked for me!